# How do I edit the theme for my Gnome Terminal? (I want to change the window title bar background to black from grey

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, gtk

xI've tried editing the following files with no success:

`/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk3.0/gtk.css`
`~/.themes/adwaita-tweaks/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

With now luck : (

What do I have to edit to get this tiny stylistic change?

**Update**

Making progress.... Editing `.themes/adwaita-tweaks/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, but! There's a stubborn bg color somewhere that keeps coming through. I'm going for black, but that dark grey seems to be filling in anywhere I leave any padding or margin.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The titlebar is a common feature that will apply to all "headerbars".

Given a that you are running against GTK3.24 (on Ubuntu 22.04 it will be GTK4.2) your headerbar could be tweaked like this:

open/create a file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and add:

```
headerbar {
  background-image:none;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

You need to log out and in again to see the effect.

This gets you a flat gray headerbar:
[image: 1]

A litte fancier could be like this:

```
headerbar {
  background-image:linear-gradient(gray,black);
}
```

which looks like this:

[image: 2]

In case you like the latter, you might check out my [theme](https://www.pling.com/p/1424967).

If GTK4 is running on your system, the gtk.css file needs to be in a `gtk-4.0` folder instead.

If you don't like the colors: instead of "black" and other color names you could use rgb colors like #2c2c2c which allows you more fine tuning.

If you want to tweak only your terminal, you'll need to download a theme (at gnome-looks or such), change it and start your terminal with:

> GTK_THEME=MyTweakedTheme gnome-terminal

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks. Now I'm down to trying to figure out where there's default background colors coming through... Updating my question.